# How to increase the performance of select query when there is more than 1 million records and growing

Tags: mysql, database, select, database-performance

I have a table which receives data from, minimum 10 different source every second.
I have divided my table into monthly bases, each month I create a table and populate the data into the table. Each table will be holding minimum 1 million records.
I have 6 fields as primary keys and indexed 7 fields.
I have not changed any other settings in MySQL (default which comes with Ubuntu).
There is only two queries will be running on the tables (insert and select)
I see that database is making my application slow.
Is there a way to improve the performance of the query.

Comment: A composite primary key with six fields? Wow, you really should be using a system key. It can also be detrimental to add too many indexes on a table, you should narrow the list down to the ones you ***really*** need.

Comment: What are your query times right now?

Comment: @jaya hi if u select data by search means u can use FULL TEXT SEARCH (MATCH AGANIST)......... It will so much faster for u........http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-search.html

Comment: @Ashwin When I am selecting more than one table it is 3 seconds per query. When I am selecting data form one table with primary or indexed keys it is 0.30 sec. When I am selecting non primary or non indexed keys it is 2 sec.

Comment: 6 primary index fields sounds **very** wrong. If you want help, you must tell more: table schema, exact queries you are making, index definitions. You can anonymize it if you must, but DO NOT omit anything

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [optimize your query using an Explain plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html), including [index optimizing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization-indexes.html) and [statement optimizing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-optimization.html), this could have a big influence on execution speed.

Answer (score 0):

First, when dealing with MySQL performances, we need to know which engine you use.

Second, we need to narrow the possible performances issues. I would say that you might have a bigger issue with the INSERT access than with the SELECT. Because, indeed, even if the SELECT query will be the slower, if the query itself is complex, the INSERT are occuring very often, and can cause you system to collapse (or just eventually slowing down the system, which will slow down your SELECT as a consequence).

So, to speed up your INSERT, I would recommand indeed to keep only the indexes you really need (typically the columns used in your SELECT WHERE clause), that would prove to be a serious improvement.

As for the optimization of the SELECT itself, without a look at the query, it's hard to help you further.